# Fail to understand why freeing memory throws an error

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I was reading to Dangling Pointer and found it's a good habit do this, to prevent oneself from dangling pointer error.

```
free(ptr); // free the ptr
ptr = NULL;
```

Now I decided to test this with a sample vanilla C code.

**CASE_1**

```
char *ptr = malloc(10);
... 
...
free(ptr); 
ptr=NULL;
// Just to check what happen if I call free more than I once
free(ptr)
ptr=NULL;
```

All work fine. Until I decided to wrap the `free` and the pointer `NULL` assignment in a `function` I named it `safefree`

```
void safefree(char *pp) {
  free(pp);
  pp = NULL;
}
```

**CASE_2**

Now, when I ran the above method more than 1 (like this)

```
safefree(ptr);

safefree(ptr);
```

I get the following error.

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x7fd98f402910: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I happen to understand the error (pointer being freed was not allocated) 
but I fail to understand why it doesn't fail in the **CASE_1** and fails in latter part of the sample code.

Comment: You can change the copy of the pointer in `safefree()`; you can't change it in the calling code with that signature.  You need: `void safefree(void **vpp) { free(*vpp); *vpp = NULL; }` — and you'd call `safefree(&ptr); safefree(&ptr);`.  And you'd have to make sure you have a `void *`.  I suppose you can stick with `char *` if you use: `void safefree(char **cpp) { free(*cpp); *cpp = NULL; }` (and `safefree(&ptr);` still), but that can only be used for freeing `char *` and not `double *`, etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Can you explain that a little bit why do I have to pass the pointer to `ptr` (pointer) in the method/function.

Comment: Because you can't modify the pointer in the calling function unless you get passed a pointer to the pointer.  Just like you can't change an `int` variable in the calling function unless the called function is passed an `int *`, you can't change a `char *` in the calling function unless the called function is passed a `char **`.

Comment: A function-like macro may be useful here... it *can* modify the pointer you pass it, without requiring an extra level of indirection.  If you keep track of your allocations well, though, you shouldn't need this normally.

Comment: @Dmitri can you provide some insight on that.

Comment: Something like `#define safefree(X) do { free(X); (X)=NULL; } while(0)` will let you just use `safefree(ptr);`.  Since it's a text substitution instead of a function call, the macro expansion , `do {free(ptr); (ptr)=NULL; } while(0);`, is part of the function you use it in, and modifies the original `ptr` and not a copy of it.  But, you should always know when you need to free your pointers and not rely on something like this to avoid having to pay attention :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's review the behaviour of `free()`. Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.3

> ```
> void free(void *ptr);
> ```
>
> The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be deallocated, that is, made
>   available for further allocation. **If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs**. Otherwise, if
>   the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management
>   function, **or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`, the
>   behavior is undefined.**

Follow the two emphasized points.

- You can pass a null pointer, `NULL`, to `free()` as many times as you want, they are valid calls (just to be ignored).
- You cannot pass a pointer which has already been passed to `free()` once.

#### Case 1:

Here, after calling `free()` with the pointer, we're **explicitly** setting the pointer to `NULL`. That is why, calling `free()` with the same pointer variable later, any number of time, is not an issue, at all.

#### case 2:

C uses pass-by-value for function argument passing. That's why, When wrapped inside a function,

```
free(pp);
```

works as expected, (it passes the required pointer to `free()`) but

```
pp = NULL;
```

is local to the function and that change is not reflected to the caller. Thereby, calling the function again causes double free, as now,

- the pointer has already been passed to `free()`
- the assigned `NULL` is not reflected to the caller, hence the pointer is not set to NULL
- in the next call, we're passing already-`free()`d pointer again.

As already mentioned, this invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

**Solution:** You need to pass a pointer to the pointer as the argument of the called function `safefree()` and from the called function, you can set the pointer value to `NULL` to get it reflected in the caller. Something like

```
void safefree(void ** ptrToPtr) 
{ 
     free(*ptrToPtr); 
     *ptrToPtr= NULL; 
 }
```

and calling like

```
 safefree (&ptrToBeFreed);
```

will do the job (*mind the types there, anyways*).

Comment: Awesome Thanks for the Explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from Jonathan's remark, if you do something that results in undefined behavior (free the pointer again), *it results in undefined behavior* (errors, crashes).

Doing the same thing in different contexts does not necessarily result in the *same* undefined behavior, it depends on implementation details; they are typically only known to the compiler developer, so they seem 'random' from the outside. Nothing much can be learned by analyzing random undefined behavior. It could for example be that the compile time affects the result..., or the spelling of the directory you work in... anything.